# When I call API in my app its shows me data as a response but in future builder, it can not show me data

Tags: api, flutter

When I call API in my app its shows me data as a response but in future builder, it can not show me data.

```
Future getMatchDataHome() async {
    List<TeamData> userdata= [];
    try {
      http.Response response =
          await http.post(Uri.parse('https://localhost:2085/api/data.json'), body: {
        'user_id': '2',
      });
      for (var tp in json.decode(response.body)['list']) {
        TeamData teamData = TeamData(
          id: '${tp['id']}',
          createrName: '${tp['creator_name']}',
        );
        userdata.add(teamData);
      }
      return userdata;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }


 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: getMatchDataHome(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          print(snapshot.data);
          if (snapshot.data == null) {
            return ProgressbarCustome() ;
          } else {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount:
                    snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  var snap = snapshot.data[index];
                  return ListTile(
                title: Text('${snap.id}'),
                trailing: Text('${snap.createrName}'),
                 );
                });
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Flutter doctor

[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.21359.1], locale en-IN)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)

[√] Chrome - develop for the web

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.9.3)

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)

[√] VS Code (version 1.56.1)

[√] Connected device (4 available)

• No issues found!

Answer (score 0):

Change `for-loop` to this:

```
 await Future.wait(json.decode(response.body)['list'].map((input) async {
     TeamData teamData = TeamData(
          id: '${tp['id']}',
          createrName: '${tp['creator_name']}',
        );
     userdata.add(teamData);
  }));

  return userdata;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to define a return type for your future:

```
Future<List<TeamData>> getMatchDataHome() async {
   ...
}
```

Most probably your FutureBuilder does not know the return type, hence it does not know that `snapshot.data` is of type `List<TeamData>`. Also, add this type to the FutureBuilder itself, like `FutureBuilder<List<TeamData>>(...)`.